# svelte keep updating store var without clicking to update

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-store

My app automatically update $content value without me clicking on buttons. I know it is a simple question, but I can't find out why, I'm learning svelte.

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import { content } from './store.js';
    import Item from './Item.svelte';


    $content = [{ id:0,obj: "Fell free to browse any category on top." }];

    function addContent(value) {
        $content = [{ id:0,obj: value}]
    }
</script>
<li><button on:click={addContent("Home Page")}>Home</button></li>
<li><button on:click={addContent("Products Page")}>Products</button></li>

<div class="Content">
    <p>Fell free to browse any category on top.</p>
    {#each $content as item}
        <p><svelte:component this={Item} objAttributes={item} /></p>
    {/each}
</div>
```

store.js

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export let content = writable({});
```

Item.svelte

```
<script>
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
    export let objAttributes = {};
    
</script>
<p transition:fade>
    {objAttributes.obj} 
    {#if objAttributes.otherattrib}<em>{objAttributes.otherattrib}</em>{/if}
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `on:click` events are defined wrongly.
The `on:click` takes as argument a function like this

```html
<button on:click={functionGoesHere}>
```

or, if you want it inlined

```html
<button on:click={() => { }>
```

What happens in your case is that you directly call a function and the result of this function will then be called when the button is clicked. You can see that in this example:

```html
<script>
  function createFn() {
    return () => console.log('logging this')
  }
</script>
<button on:click={createFn}>Click here</button>
```

in this example the function `() => console.log('logging this')` will be attached the button.

So to come back to your code, this is easily fixed by making it a function instead of a function call:

```html
<li><button on:click={() => addContent("Home Page")}>Home</button></li>
```